# Opening Xcode project with two pods installed

Tags: xcode, frameworks, cocoapods

I'm trying to add to my app both Moltin and Firebase pods. I know that if I want to open the file (with only one pod installed) I need to open it from the .xcworkspace file instead of using the .xcodeproj file.

Which file do I have to open if I have more than one pod installed (and so two .xcworkspace files)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After you install your first pod, you should always use `.xcworkspace`.

It doesn't matter how many pods you have installed, after the first one, always use `.xcworkspace`.

In other words:

0 pods, use `.xcodeproj`

1+ pods, use `.xcworkspace`

---

There will only be **one** `.xcworkspace`.

Comment: Your last sentence is not technically correct. There will only be one workspace file, but there will be one project file per pod + your own project (which itself might consist of several project files). The whole point of a workspace is that it can contain several projects and hence project files.

Answer (score 2):

You can install more than one pods in podFile , as Gustavo said , There will only be one Podfile in a project.Create it once and add pods into Podfile whatever you want like :

```
target 'AppName' do

frameworks
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Moltin'
  ...
```

Comment: Your comment line wrapped, so the last word isn’t a comment anymore. Can you fix that, to avoid confusion?

Comment: Updated. Thanks @Nate

Answer (score 2):

Xcode workspace is a directory (not a file) which has a `.xcworkspace` extension. Finder shows it as a package. It actually is an Xcode document that groups projects and other documents so can be worked together in your project.

> A workspace can contain any number of Xcode projects, plus any other files you want to include.
>
> When you open an `XCWORKSPACE`, it opens the associated project and restores the perspective. Therefore, Xcode workspace files can be used as a wrapper or container for an Xcode `.XCODEPROJ` project.

Xcode workspace directory includes a vital XML file named `contents.xcworkspacedata`, and it looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Workspace
   version = "1.0">
   <FileRef
      location = "group:MySampleProject.xcodeproj">
   </FileRef>
   <FileRef
      location = "group:OtherProject(for example Pods).xcodeproj">
   </FileRef>
</Workspace>
```

In this arbitrary tree, `group:` represents the directory of your project/s (as many you have). 
Additionally `.xcworkspace` always exists it may be external to an `.xcodeproj`, or embedded within one. Therefore, whenever you see `.xcworkspace` you have to use it to open your project.

Comment: You're most welcome. Please accept and check one of the answers that is most helpful for you.